# Why does MongoDB not update unless I call ".then res.json(...)" after findOneAndUpdate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern

understanding questions here. I am doing a MERN setup website, and I was updating a field in my database like this:

```
router.post("/updateLogApprovementStatus", (req, res) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.body.userId },
    { $set: { log: req.body.newData } }
  ).then(user => res.json(user.log));
});
```

But after doing repeated calls to the api with correct data, my data field wasn't updating. However, when I do this:

```
router.post("/updateLogApprovementStatus", (req, res) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.body.userId },
    { $set: { log: req.body.newData } }
  ).then(user => res.json(user.log));
});
```

My database updates perfectly fine. All I did was adding a res.json(), which occurs after the update since it is in the "then" statement, which makes me wonder why it wored. 
I am pretty sure that all I did was adding the then res.json() statement. Any clarifications on why this made it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason being : ["The query executes if callback is passed else a Query object is returned."](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) (bellow the returns section)

`.then()` isn't really a promise, it's disguised by mongoose but acts as an execution.

You can see it execute queries [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises)

`.exec()` from the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) "Executes the query" and returns a Promise (true one)

> Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a .then() function for co
> and async/await as a convenience. If you need a fully-fledged promise,
> use the .exec() function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you should go with something like this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.body.userId },
  { $set: { log: req.body.newData } }
).exec();
```

The exec function will run the query and this way you don't have to handle the promise result.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make sense. I was asking why my mongoDB doesn't update unless I handle the promise result. Without .then, for some reason, the findOneAndUpdate part doesn't get handled. Which is really weird. But there is probably a high chance that my tests weren't perfected and a few errors happened during the testing process.