# findOneAndUpdate does not update unless I call ".then()". Why?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my call to `findOneAndUpdate` does not update anything unless I handle the returned promise with `.then()`. I don't care what the call returns so I don't bother to handle the promise.

This does not work:

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({key: 'XXXXX'}, {$set: {status: 'complete'}})
```

This works:

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({key: 'XXXXX'}, {$set: {status: 'complete'}}).then()
```

Appending a `.then()` at the end certainly doesn't hurt me in any way, but I am simply curious as to why the call doesn't work without it. Shouldn't it still execute the query?

This guys seems to be asking the same question, but as of yet it's still unresolved: [Why does MongoDB not update unless I call ".then res.json(...)" after findOneAndUpdate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55885732/1927991)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being : ["The query executes if callback is passed else a Query object is returned."](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

.then() executes the function as seen [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises)

> For example, the below code will execute 3 updateMany() calls, one
> because of the callback, and two because .then() is called twice.

```
const q = MyModel.updateMany({}, { isDeleted: true }, function() {
  console.log('Update 1');
});

q.then(() => console.log('Update 2'));
q.then(() => console.log('Update 3'));
```

Comment: Where did you get this quote? "The query executes if callback is passed else a Query object is returned."

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate documentation, bellow "returns". Would this solve your problem/question ?

Comment: The doc is pretty clear indeed. This explains it. As for using `exec()`, with all due respect, that wasn't my question. It works just fine with the `then()`, I was only wondering as to **why**.

Comment: Indeed it wasn't your question ahah. You can see here exactly why then() executes your query https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises : "For example, the below code will execute 3 updateMany() calls, one because of the callback, and two because .then() is called twice."

Comment: Modified it to reflect better your question :) nice day ! (I also answered the other link you posted, maybe this person will see it)